# With jQuery, I need to determine the last visible input in a fieldset

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a codepen that shows my issue: http://codepen.io/esdictor/pen/KdqeEV

**Structure**: I have a form that contains fieldsets. Each fieldset contains FormRows (div class="FormRow"). Each FormRow contains Fields (div class="FormField"). Each field generally contains a single form element (input, select, textarea, etc, but for this example I'll stick to inputs). So:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Group 1</legend>
        <div class="FormRow">
            <div class="FormField">
                <label for="Test1">Test1</label>
                <input type="text" id="Test1" />
            </div>
            <div class="FormField">
                <label for="Test2">Test2</label>
                <input type="text" id="Test2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>>
```

**Requirements**: My page needs to react to the last input in each fieldset, except the final fieldset. I came up with a selector that worked fine at first:

```
$('form fieldset:not(:last-of-type) .FormRow:last-of-type .FormField:last-of-type input')
```

**The Problem**: Recently I was given some new elements that might be hidden based on other data in the form, and in the case where those were at the end of a fieldset and WERE hidden, my code no longer worked.

**My Example**: The codepen linked above has a hidden TextA input (actually, the entire FormRow is hidden) in the Group 2 fieldset. Because this is hidden, the Test9 input should be red. However, I have been unable to come up with a selector to take this into account.

**NOTE** This form is data-driven and used for many different types of data, so I can't hardcode anything. I need to just "know" when the control is the last visible control in the fieldset so I can write my event accordingly.

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you select the last `FormField` (or event the last `FormRow`) it could not have any visible input.

You could do this:

```
$('form fieldset:not(:last-of-type) .FormRow:last-of-type:has(input:visible) .FormField:last-of-type:has(input:visible) input:visible')
```

Or to avoid the very complex selector:

```
$('form fieldset:not(:last-of-type)').each(function() {
    var $fieldset = $(this),
        $input = $fieldset.find("input:visible:last");
    if ($input.length > 0)
        // Do your work here
        $input.css("background-color", "red");
});
```

**Based on comments** you could also use:

```
$('form fieldset:not(:last-of-type) .FormRow:last-of-type .FormField:last-of-type input, form fieldset:not(:last-of-type) input:visible:last')
```

Comment: Neither of your selectors gives me the answer, but one of them did highlight Test9 correctly (CodePen is down at the moment so I can't remember which one). I feel like this brings me much closer to the correct answer.

Comment: The reason why I was looking for a selector, is that I need this for events, not for a color change. The only way I could use the code you have there now would be if I ran that initially to set a new class (like .IsLastInput) and then use that for my event.

Comment: This seems to work (based on your initial response): `$('form fieldset:not(:last-of-type) .FormRow:last-of-type .FormField:last-of-type input, form fieldset:not(:last-of-type) input:visible:last').css('background-color', '#FF0000');` Need to do more testing. If it comes out ok I'll ask you to post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible to achieve what you need in one selector. Maybe you should bind the event and check if its the right input when event is fired.

Comment: So my last comment, adding your `, form fieldset:not(:last-of-type) input:visible:last` to the end of my original string, works like a charm. If you post that as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the ":visible" selector.

```
$('form fieldset:not(:last-of-type) .FormRow:last-of-type .FormField:last-of-type input:visible')
```

Or if its the FormField being hidden this:

```
$('form fieldset:not(:last-of-type) .FormRow:last-of-type .FormField:last-of-type:visible input')
```